# PHP FCKeditor skin path problem?

Tags: php, fckeditor

I can't seem to change the skin path using the `FCKConfig.SkinPath = FCKConfig.BasePath + 'skins/silver/' ;` form the http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Configuration/Configuration_Options/SkinPath tutorial. I get the following error listed below. How do I fix this?

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='
```

Here is the FCKeditor PHP code below.

```
<?php
$oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor('FCKeditor1') ;
$oFCKeditor->BasePath = '../../fckeditor/' ;
$oFCKeditor->Value = '<p>This is some <strong>sample text</strong>. You are using <a href="http://www.fckeditor.net/">FCKeditor</a>.</p>' ;
$oFCKeditor->Create() ;
?>
```

Here is the FCKeditor with the skin code.

```
<?php
$oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor('FCKeditor1') ;
$oFCKeditor->BasePath = '../../fckeditor/' ;
FCKConfig.SkinPath = FCKConfig.BasePath + 'skins/silver/' ;
$oFCKeditor->Value = '<p>This is some <strong>sample text</strong>. You are using <a href="http://www.fckeditor.net/">FCKeditor</a>.</p>' ;
$oFCKeditor->Create() ;
?>
```

Line 5 is giving me the problem.

Comment: Which exact line is it giving you the syntax error for? PHP usually provides a line number along with it's error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Javascript syntax, but you must use the PHP integration: http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Integration/PHP